# Windows Logon Logs deleted

Tags: windows, events, logging, recovery

I have some how lost my Security Logs prior to today 01:57:11 pm. The file size I had assigned to Security Logs was 160MB. Today (maybe due to virus) I have 273,692 new logs in just few hours so all previous logs are lost. The policy I set was to overwrite oldest logs if file size exceeded. I saved them as csv file and the .csv file size is about 150MB. and the logs count upto 273694
In C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs Security has 160MB.

I have attached the picture for reference. All I need is: Logon logs on this computer from 12 hours prior to the last Security event log time.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this problem.[image]

Thanks

Comment: Solve what problem? If you have set your Domain policy or Local policy to override older logs, i don't see how you can recover this. Except you want to do a system restore

Comment: I kinda solved my problem. I looked on the events when group policy was applied on users, So now I got the missing users from this technique. Actually this is a university lab computer so many students log onto this and we apply group policy on them. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the logon Group Policy event logs. From that i was able to see missing users on whom the logon group policy was applied to.